# How to find the reliable dependency packages with NPM?

Tags: javascript, npm

for example, adding a new dependency package with shell:

```
npm install typescript
```

I don't know anything about the provider of that package.

In contrast, with maven (a package manager using in Java), add some new dependency package by changing the xml config file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>31.1-jre</version>
</dependency>
```

At least, I know the provider has some relationship with the domain owner of "google.com".

Comment: you need to visit `npmjs.com` and look for source code (usually there will be github repo url), then see who is maintaining it or which organization has it. eg [googleapis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/googleapis) package is in under [googleapis](https://github.com/googleapis) org, which is linked to google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using some provider for your packages e.g. `npmjs` or `yarnpkg` (almost all of the alternatives are just mirrors of npmjs just like maven-central for java)

You can for example search for [Typescript there](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript) and you will get the information you need.

Tbh is way easier to publish something malicious to npmjs and its a common issue (for example packages fishing for typos) also dependencies are often not overseeable in larger projects.

Some packages also have scopes similar to groupids in maven. For example `@vue/cli` and `@vue/test-utils` are all in the scope `@vue`

Your downloads are reliable. They will have hashes in your `package-lock.json` and if you install with `npm ci` instead of `npm install` you will always install the exact same version.